# Grep: Match a programming language

Tags: shell, grep

I have a directory with many files. The files contain summaries of people that describe their experience using a programming language.

The problem comes when i want to match a programming language that has only one letter like `C`.

For the others i have no problem.

```
grep C++
grep Ada
grep Pascal
grep Scheme
```

How can i make a grep to match `C` and not confuse it with other words presented in the files?

Comment: Same story bro, we still need a sample file. How can anyone create better answer than `search for " C "` without any additional context?

Comment: @Iskustvo I'd go for `grep -w C` myself, or even `grep -P '\bC\b'`

Comment: Could the summary say "I'm not very good with `C`", and should that match?  What if they list experience with `K&RC` ?  We need to see a good example of the input.

Comment: @roaima Judging from the other question he posted, I would say he is familiar with both of those methods and probably needs something more complex.

Comment: @Iskustvo i don't need complex format.

Comment: Example that it should match : Today i started to program in C.

Comment: @AndresZW Ok, then `grep -w C` is good enough?

Comment: @Iskustvo it also matched C++

Comment: Of course it did. Please provide examples IN YOUR QUESTION so it's easy for people to validate their suggestions before posting them.

Comment: @AndresZW If have answered the question correctly, please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to match the single letter `C` then you should be able to do this with `grep` easily enough. Add the `-i` flag for case-insensitive matching.

```
grep -w C *
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
grep -- "\<C\>" your_file
```

This would also match `I like C, because ...`.

Answer (score 0):

In general your solution should be `grep -w C` or `grep -P '\bC\b'`, like [roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100397/roaima) suggested.

To ignore special cases like `C++`, you can always use negative look-ahead:

```
grep -P "\bC\b(?!\+)" file
```

`(?!\+)` makes `grep` ignore the match if the first following character after `C` is a `+`.
If there are more specific cases, you can just edit this part of code to match them also.